# React app: Images from firebase are not shown on a page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, firebase

I want to display images on a page that come from firebase. I can successfully get urls from the storage but when I use them in image as a src, they (images) are not shown.
[image]
As you can see from the image above, image tags are blank. I don't know what is the problem. Could suggest me a way out. My code is the following:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { firebase } from '../../../firebase';
import AdminLayout from '../../../Hoc/AdminLayout';
import { firebasePhotos } from '../../../firebase';
import { firebaseLooper, reverseArray } from '../../ui/misc';
import { css } from 'react-emotion';
import { BarLoader } from 'react-spinners';
import { confirmAlert } from 'react-confirm-alert';
import 'react-confirm-alert/src/react-confirm-alert.css';

class Adminphoto extends Component {
  state = {
    isLoading: true,
    photos: [],
    marginTop: '40px',
    successForm: ''
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    firebasePhotos.once('value').then(snapshot => {
      const photos = firebaseLooper(snapshot);
      this.setState({
        isLoading: false,
        marginTop: '0px',
        photos: reverseArray(photos)
      });
    });
  }

  getURL = filename => {
    //console.log(filename);
    firebase
      .storage()
      .ref('photos')
      .child(filename)
      .getDownloadURL()
      .then(url => {
        console.log('url =>' + url);
        return url;
      });
  };

  successForm(message) {
    this.setState({
      successForm: message
    });

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({
        formSuccess: ''
      });
    }, 2000);
  }

  deleteItem(event, photo) {
    event.preventDefault();
    confirmAlert({
      title: 'Confirm to submit',
      message: 'Are you sure to do this.',
      buttons: [
        {
          label: 'Yes',
          onClick: () => {
            firebasePhotos
              .child(photo.id)
              .remove()
              .then(() => {
                this.successForm('Removed successfully');
                this.props.history.push('/admin_photo');
              });
          }
        },
        {
          label: 'No',
          onClick: () => {
            return false;
          }
        }
      ]
    });
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.photos);
    const override = css`
      display: block;
      margin: 0 auto;
      border-color: red;
    `;
    return (
      <AdminLayout>
        <React.Fragment>
          <div
            className="has-text-centered"
            style={{ marginTop: this.state.marginTop }}
          >
            {this.state.isLoading ? (
              <BarLoader
                className={override}
                sizeUnit={'px'}
                size={50}
                width={100}
                height={4}
                color={'#2D7969'}
                loading={this.state.loading}
              />
            ) : (
              ''
            )}
          </div>
          <div className="columns">
            {this.state.photos
              ? this.state.photos.map((photo, i) => (
                  <div key={i} className="column">
                    <img src={this.getURL(photo.image)} />
                  </div>
                ))
              : null}
          </div>
        </React.Fragment>
      </AdminLayout>
    );
  }
}

export default Adminphoto;
```

Comment: did the `console.log('url =>' + url);` print anything? if so, what do they print?

Comment: Hi, it prints the actual url, that is working.

Comment: OH, `getURL() ` does not wait for firebase `getDownloadURL()` to resolve, it is async right?  so in the `then()` you better store the url in the state, then the element should get the url from the state

Comment: When I tried to do so I caught an infinite loop.

Comment: well, but not you know why it prints empty `<img>`, keep trying while i modify your code.

Comment: Ok, thanks! I will try my best.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186604/discussion-between-nzmai-and-nikko-khresna).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

changes i made:
 1. `this.state.photos` to be the img src
 2. `this.getURL()` is called in `componentDidMount()`
 3. `<img>` gets src directly from state

```
  componentDidMount() {
    firebasePhotos.once('value').then(snapshot => {
      const photos = firebaseLooper(snapshot);

      reverseArray(photos).map(photo => {
        this.getURL(photo.image)
      })

      this.setState({
        isLoading: false,
        marginTop: '0px',
      })
    });
  }

  getURL = filename => {
    //console.log(filename);
    firebase
      .storage()
      .ref('photos')
      .child(filename)
      .getDownloadURL()
      .then(url => {
        this.setState({ photos: [...this.state.photos, url] })
      });
  };

  render() {
  ...
              this.state.photos.map((photo, i) => (
                  <div key={i} className="column">
                    <img src={photo} />
                  </div>
                ))
  ...
```

hope it works, lemme know if im not really clear at explaining

Comment: Hi Nikko! It doesn't display pics, as src="[object object]". You can see the pic https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Yr6bCf0n8fXvW_Oc42rs-umHlDjUaD5v

Comment: Oh...glad it does...keep it up...u did well

Comment: Your solution is quite unusual! How did you get it right?

Comment: Haha really? It is just async method that messed your component. Thats how i usually deal with async code. Since it does not return anything when you say `return`, you need fo store it somewhere where your `render()` can access after the async code complete the execution.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to save url of image in the firebase realtime database and then get them from database and save them in the state.

You can manually save the urls in the database while uploading them or write cloud function triggers which will save urls in the database, every time image is uploaded in the firebase storage.

Comment: Thanks for your help!